# Is it possible to directly interact the time variable with another variable in survival analysis? Or is that what a log rank test is for? stata

Tags: survival, interaction, stata

Is it possible to directly interact the time variable with another variable in survival analysis? Or is that what a log rank test is for? Working in Stata and I get this error when I try to interact the time variable with another variable (see screen shot). Other interactions seem to be working.

`stset dx_lastcontact_death_years, failure(died) exit (time 11) stcox i.stdcare_or_no  i.raceethnicity#c.dx_lastcontact_death_years i.raceethnicity age i.year_group_div i.sex i.charlson_group i.ins_group i.income_group_16 i.education_group i.`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to have an interaction of time elapsed since `time = 0` with a variable in a Cox model. That's, for example, how you can model time-varying coefficient values. But it requires special steps.

What you seem to have done is to create an interaction between the *last observation time* and a *predictor* in the model for each case. But the last observation time is an *outcome* in your data. The [time dependence vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survival/vignettes/timedep.pdf) of the R [`survival` package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=survival) discusses the implication of such an interaction variable:

> This variable most definitely breaks the rule about not looking into the future, and one would quickly find the circularity: large values of `time` appear to predict long survival because long survival leads to large values for `time`.

This circular logical structure is probably why why your model failed even to converge.

In R you can set up a correct interaction between a function of continuous time since `time = 0` (not just the last observation time) and a covariate, via a `tt()` term in a Cox model. I suspect there is something similar in Stata.

This has nothing directly to do with a log-rank test, which is just a test of whether there are any differences among a set of survival curves.